# Stationary OU process

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let
$$
           Y_t = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\mu}}
           e^{-\mu t}W(e^{2\mu t}),
$$
where $W(t)\equiv W_t$ is the standard Brownian motion, $\sigma,\mu>0$.  I wonder how to show that $Y_t$ is a stationary Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. I think maybe I can show that it's a stationary Gaussian process with
$\mathbb{E}[Y_{\tau+s}Y_s]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{\tau}Y_0]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : Go the other way round and show that if $Y(t)$ is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process then the process $Z_t$ given by

\begin{align}
Z_t =t^{\frac12}\frac{\sqrt{2\mu}}{\sigma} Y\left(\frac{1}{2\mu}\log t\right) \, ,
\end{align}
is a standard Brownian motion.

Comment: Sorry, could you say more about this? Are you proving by contrapositive?

Comment: No its not the contrapositive. If the above process $Z_t$ is a Brownian motion then your formula holds true because you can just rescale time  as $(2\mu)^{-1}\log t \mapsto s$ to land up at your formula.